# Merged Resource Dictionary failed to assign to property

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, dictionary, resourcedictionary

Similar question like this have been asked. Some have been answered (but not for my case), others have not. I have a simple Silverlight app project, a second Silverlight class library project with a UserControl, and a third project with a bunch of resource dictionaries. The project structure looks like this:

Silverlight app project:

```
Client.Login
  - App.xaml
  - MainPage.xaml
```

Silverlight library projectwith UserControl:

```
Client.UX.Login
 - Login.xaml <<- The user control

Client.UX.ResourceDictionaries
 - Buttoms.xaml
 - ComboBoxes.xaml
 - etc...
```

`Client.UX.Login` has a project reference to `Client.UX.ResourceDictionaries` and it includes these dictionaries as needed like this within Login.xaml's UserControl:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>            
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.UX.ResourceLibraries;component/Brushes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.UX.ResourceLibraries;component/TextBoxes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.UX.ResourceLibraries;component/PasswordBoxes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.UX.ResourceLibraries;component/Buttons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.UX.ResourceLibraries;component/ComboBoxes.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Client.UX.ResourceLibraries;component/RadioButtons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

`Client.Login` references ONLY the UserControl's library: Client.UX.Login.

When I run the app, I get the following error on the the first ResourceDictionary merge in the XAML above:

```
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'.
```

The inner exception is a `KeyNotFoundException` however the only XAML in Brushes.xaml is very very simple. Just a few button-related styles.

I can resolve the issue by adding a reference to `Client.UX.ResourceLibraries` in `Client.Login`, but that defeats the purpose of separating out the ResourceLibraries, right?

Does any one know why a resource dictionary as a secondary project reference would throw this type of exception? Or how to resolve this issue without supplying the root project with a direct reference to the library with the resources in it?

Comment: Interesting question, although I would just reference style library directly in `Client.Login`. Its better to have style that affects all similar controls in application, not just some specific custom controls IMHO. This way app will look more consistent and is easier to theme if needed.

Comment: icebat, if I reference those libraries from my app's project what is the point of separating the UserControl into a separate assembly? I don't want my app to "know" about those references. Just the references it needs.

Comment: Can you zip and provide a link to your code?

Comment: @Aaron, if you don\`t plan to use that UserControl in some other project then there\`s no point indeed, but that goes only for control itself, not style dictionary. It\`s better for custom control to abide by application style, so I don\`t see any real need to make such reference chains for style libraries.

Comment: icebat, I do plan to use the UserControl in another project. That is the whole point of organizing the projects that way and why I don't think it should be necessary to reference the libraries project from the parent (root) project.

Comment: Also, if it's better for a "custom control to abide by the application's style", how would you break up your styles into separate projects so as to avoid putting them all in App.xaml *and* so that your designer can use Expression Blend effectively?